# Is it possible to find variable from datagridview ColumnName?

Tags: c#, winforms, variables, datagridview

I have strange question. I have `DataGridView` and I have 7 columns that are filled with doubles. I have 7 arrays of double in the main class that contains the information.

How can I make something like this:

```
if(dgvValues.Columns[dgvValues.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex].Name == this.Variables.Name)
{
       this.Variables.Name[dgvValues.SelectedCells[0].RowIndex] = Convert.ToDouble(dgvValues.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString());
}
```

I know I can do it with case but I wonder is there a short way of doing it. Because if I have 20 columns I have to make 20 cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put those values in a `Dictionary<string, List<double>>`!

Now you can access each by the the dgv column names..:

```
// a named collection of lists of doubles:
Dictionary<string, List<double>> values = new Dictionary<string, List<double>>();

// set up the values-dictionary from column names:
foreach (DataGridViewColumn column in dataGridView1.Columns)
{
    values.Add(column.Name, new List<double>());
}

// load all values into the values-dictionary from the dvg:
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in row.Cells)
        values[cell.OwningColumn.Name].Add( Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value) );
}

// after the List is filled (!) you can access it like an array:
// load selected values into the values-dictionary from the dvg:
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
    values[cell.OwningColumn.Name][cell.RowIndex] = Convert.ToDouble(cell.Value);
}

// reload selected values from the corresponding slots in the values-dictionary:
foreach (DataGridViewCell cell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
{
    cell.Value = values[cell.OwningColumn.Name][cell.RowIndex];
}
```

Note that you must have filled the lists completely with all rows to access the right slots, when you use the array indexer!

Comment: I thought about this way, but is there any other way to do this?

Comment: There is always reflection, but this is probably the most efficient way to access named variables. Any reasons why you don't like it?

Comment: Well I didn't say I don't like it, just wondering is there more efficient way. Thanks marking as answer. :)

Comment: Thanks. Dictionaries and Lists __are__ efficient.